# Using Python to change string variable into JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm using python. I have a variable named "var" that has square brackets which I want to remove and change it to a valid JSON. Is there an easy way to do this? I've been trying, but still no luck.

```
var = '''
 [
    [
      "result 1"
    ],
    [
      "result 2"
    ],
    [
      "result 3"
    ],
    [
      "result 4"
    ],
    [
      "result 5"
    ],
    [
      "result 6"
    ],
    [
      "result 7"
    ]
  ]
'''
```

> GOAL RESULT

```
  {
    "result 1": "result 1",
    "result 2": "result 2",
    "result 3": "result 3",
    "result 4": "result 4",
    "result 5": "result 5",
    "result 6": "result 6",
    "result 7": "result 7"
  }
```

> What I tried

```
  def listToStringWithoutBrackets(list1):
    return "{" + str(list1).replace('[','').replace(']','') + "}"

print(listToStringWithoutBrackets(var))
```

Comment: This *is* valid JSON as is. You just want to turn it from an array with arrays with single elements into an object. For that, parse the JSON, turn the arrays into your desired object structure (`{i[0]: i[0] for i in parsed_json}`) and JSON-encode it again.

Comment: @deceze I will try what you suggested. Thank you for commenting. I've been stuck trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var is already valid json, just convert list array to dictionary.

```
import json

data = json.loads(var)
new_json = {}
# convert list to dictionary
for i in data:
    new_json[i[0]] = i[0]

# create string as json
new_var = json.dumps(new_json)
print(new_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to transform json-like object to dict-like object.
you just transformed it to string but not to dictionary.

**Codes** are as follows.
Hope to help you!

```
import json

var = '''
 [
    [
      "result 1"
    ],
    [
      "result 2"
    ],
    [
      "result 3"
    ],
    [
      "result 4"
    ],
    [
      "result 5"
    ],
    [
      "result 6"
    ],
    [
      "result 7"
    ]
  ]
'''
def json_TO_dict(jsonlike_obj):
    jsoned_obj=json.loads(jsonlike_obj)
    json_dict={}
    for content in jsoned_obj:
        json_dict[content[0]]=content[0]
    return json_dict

print(json_TO_dict(var))
```

**results** are as follows.

```
{
'result 1': 'result 1', 
'result 2': 'result 2', 
'result 3': 'result 3', 
'result 4': 'result 4', 
'result 5': 'result 5', 
'result 6': 'result 6', 
'result 7': 'result 7'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below assuming json_data is your json input:

```
op = json.loads(json_data)
print({x[0]: x[0] for x in op})
```